# How could I display alert jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I'm trying use Jquery with cakephp. To do it I created an `Element` and created a `<header>` to include css and jquery `echo $this->Html->script("jquery-2.1.4");`. In `default.ctp` I added header. 
To test if jquery it's working I'm trying display an `alert()` but doesn`t works.

How could I display an alert() with jquery in cakephp ?

I'm trying this.

**View**

```
<?php
//display alert when view is renderer(loaded)
$this->Html->scriptBlock(
        "$(document).ready(function () { "
        . "alert('JQuery is succesfully included'); "
        . "});",
        array('inline'=>false));
?>


<div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-heading">
        Adicionar - Usuário
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>  
                    <div class="form-group">                                            
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('pessoas_id', array("label"=>"Pessoa",
                                                                          "empty"=>"Selecione uma opção",
                                                                          "placeholder"=>"Informe a pessoa", 
                                                                          "style"=>"width:200px",
                                                                          "class"=>"form-control"));?>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">                         
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('nome', array("label"=>"Nome",
                                                                     "placeholder"=>"Informe o nome",                                                                                               
                                                                     "class"=>"form-control"));?>                        

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">                                            
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array("label"=>"Email",
                                                                     "placeholder"=>"Informe o email",                                                                                               
                                                                     "class"=>"form-control"));?>                        

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">                                            
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('senha', array("type"=>"password",                                                                    
                                                                     "maxlength"=>8,                                                                     
                                                                     "style"=>"width:200px;",
                                                                     "class"=>"form-control"));?>                        

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">   
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('role', array(
                                                      "class"=>"form-control",
                                                      "style"=>"width:200px;",
                                                      "empty"=>"Selecione uma opção",
                                                      'options' => array('admin' => 'Administrador', 'privado' => 'Privado')))?>


                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Gravar</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-success">Limpar</button>
                <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
            </div>            
        </div>
        <span><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Listar'), array('action' => 'index')); ?></span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: First view the html source and see if jquery is actually included and visit the jquery url in the browser to make sure that its actually included correctly.

Comment: Check the page source if the code is appended.

Comment: Look at in Chrome Tools of Developer the jquery is loaded in header, but I dont know how can I show the alert.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
echo $this->Js->buffer("$(document).ready(function(){alert('JQuery is succesfully included');});");
```

But if you want to show the alert when ALL the content is loaded, you should use the `load()` jquery function, it is triggered when all the content is loaded (images included).